# How to calculate value of force required to move CNC rounter?

Tags: cnc

I want to design CNC rounter. I want to know how much force required to move router in to material.
How to consider this.
I guess there are many factor like

1. Material
2. Feed rate
3. Depth of cut
4. number of cutting tool's flute.

I don't want to try out and error for this please give me some clue.

Comment: Can you please share some details of your research?

Comment: Sorry I am robotics engineer I can design control circuit design mechanism to provide necessary force. But I don’t know what exact force I needed.

Comment: It is helpful to share your circuit design knowledge in the body of the question, to help generate target responses. Also there are many CNC router designs in the market. Tell us what the intended target.

Comment: Still in design process. but I planned to use GRBL based but the driver and motor I must calculate required torque first. the answer of NMech seem not much force required.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need much "pushing" force to cut away material. The router does not remove material by pushing it on to a surface.

What happens is that you approach the router to the surface and the tips of the cutting bit remove thin slivers of the materias as they rotate. So what you do is move at small steps at different depths.

What you need to know is the torque that your router needs to resist while cutting. I.e as the material is removed a torsional moment (aka torque) develops. You'd need to be able to resist that. The maximum value should be greater to the maximum torque of the router.